# How can I make my website's scaling mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a Django app and I have issues with the mobile view of the page. Some elements are not displayed correctly.
I would be greatful, if someone could help me correct them.

I have a default.html which is displayed on all pages.
It contains the logged-in user's name, the Create New article and the Logout buttons. In mobile view, they are totally messed up.

I have a pagination.html, which messed up in mobile view as well.
I posted two screenshots about the problem. Included the css, the pagination.html and the default.html

Thnak you in advance!

This is the css:

```
body{
    background-color: #0f121f;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}

body *{
    font-family: Ubuntu;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

a, a:hover, a:visited{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.wrapper h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-size: 2.4em;
}

.wrapper .create-article h2{
    color: #00dba0;
}

header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
/*
.Paginating_stuff{
    margin-top: 10px;
    pagination-disabled-bg:
}
.page-link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    color: #00dba0;
    background-color: #00dba0;
}
li.page-item.disabled{
    background-color: #00dba0;
}
*/
.create_logout_nav{
    justify-self: end;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.create_logout_nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.UpdateArticle li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
a.ArticleEdit{
    border: 1px solid #00dba0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #00dba0;
    transition: background 1s ease-out 100ms;
}
a.ArticleEdit:hover{
    color: #0f121f;
    border-color: #00dba1cc;
    background: #00dba1cc;
    transition: border 0.2s ease-out;
}
a.ArticleDelete{
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid #db000052;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #00dba0;
    background: #db0000ad;
    /*transition: background 1s ease-out 100ms;*/
}
a.ArticleDelete:hover{
    color: #0f121f;
    border-color: #db000052;
    background: #db0000ad;
    /*transition: border 0.2s ease-out;*/
}
/*
nav{
    justify-self: end;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
*/
nav button{
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.pagination-set{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pagination li a{
    background-color: #0f121f !important;
    color:#00dba0 !important;
    border-color: #fff !important;
}

.pagination li.active a{
    color:#0f121f !important;
    background-color: #00dba0 !important;
    border-color: #fff !important;
}

.articles{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.article{
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.article h2{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.article-details .article{
    padding: 0;
}

.article-details .article img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.article-details .article h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.articles_list{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.article_list{
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.article_list:hover{
    background-color: #00bda179;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.article_list h2{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.author{
    text-align: right;
}

.site-form input, .site-form textarea{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.site-form, .site-form input{
    text-align: center,
}
/*
a.highlight{
    padding: 11px;
}

a.highlight:hover{
    border: 1px solid #00dba0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #00dba0;
}
*/
a.highlight{
    border: 1px solid #00dba0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #00dba0;
    transition: background 1s ease-out 100ms;
}
a.highlight:hover{
    color: #0f121f;
    border-color: #00dba1cc;
    background: #00dba1cc;
    transition: border 0.2s ease-out;
}

form.logout-link:hover{
    color: black;
}

.helptext{
    display: flex;
}
```

This is the default.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" property="og:description" content="These articles are about movies and created by users.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="seo, python, django, movies, articles, opinions, posts, users">
        <meta name="author" content="...">
        <title>Articles</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'logo5.png' %}" /></a></h1>
            <nav class="create_logout_nav">
                <ul>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li>Hi, {{ user.username }}</li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:create' %}" class="highlight">Create new article</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the related logout part:
It contains the logged-in user's name, the Create New article and the Logout buttons:

[image: The logout button and the other text]

I tried an idea to fix the username, the Create New article and the Logout buttons.
I changed the `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline-flex;`:

```
.create_logout_nav li{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

But it just created a bigger Create New article button:

[image: bigger Create New article button]

I have the same issue with the pagination as well:

[image: Pagination]

Here is the pagination.html:

```
{% if items.has_other_pages %}
    <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center pagination-set">
        <nav aria-label="">
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                {% if items.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo First</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }}"><<</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for i in page_range %}
                    {% if items.number == i %}
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <a class="page-link" href="">{{i}}<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if items.has_next %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" aria-label="Next" href="?page={{items.next_page_number}}">>></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Here is my login.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        {% if request.GET.next %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my signup.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <form class="site-form" action="/accounts/signup/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Signup">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my article_list.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Article list</h1>
    <div class="articles_list">
        {% for article in items %}
        <div class="article_list">
            <a href="{% url 'articles:details' slug=article.slug %}">
            <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
            <p><img src="{{ article.thumb.url }}"/></p>
            <p>{{ article.short_desc }}</p></a>
            <p>{{ article.author }}, {{ article.date }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include 'articles/pagination.html' %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my article_create.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="create-article">
    <h2>Create a new article</h2>
    <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'articles:create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="/static/slugify.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my article_list.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if article.author.id == user.id %}
    <nav class="UpdateArticle">
        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:edit' slug=article.slug %}" class="ArticleEdit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:delete' slug=article.slug %}" class="ArticleDelete">Delete</a></li>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
<div class="article-details">
    <div class="article">
        <img src="{{ article.thumb.url }}"/>
        <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
        <div class="infos">
            <p>Director: {{ article.director }}</p>
            <p>Protagonist(s): {{ article.protagonist }}</p>
        </div>
        <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
        <p class="author">Created by <br>{{ article.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my article_form.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="create-article">
    <h2>Edit an article</h2>
    <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'articles:edit' slug=article.slug %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="/static/slugify.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Browsers use responsive design by default, but your styles prevent that. You can restrict the broad screen stuff using media queries (`min-width` etc.). Another common technique is using `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` to allow automatic layout changes when needed.

Comment: Hi @IngoSteinke. Thank you for your comment. It worked for the header. I tried to apply it to the pagination but didn't work. Is it a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is going to be a question, and I'm sorry about that:

### Some questions

What do you want to realize in the end?
"Scaling mobile friendly" could mean different things depending on your target, but also on your skills.

By default, the web is responsive: texts and sections on your website will (almost) never overflow and fill (almost) nicely the size of your screen.

### Practical aspect

What you need in your case is going back to a more flexible state.
If you want us to help you, please share the complete HTML and CSS so we can reproduce your case.

### Some ideas

```
header.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* allows your content to wrap in case of need */
    justify-content: space-between; /* just put space between the two children */
}
```

If you want to force a specific behavior under a certain screen size:

```
/* Under 640px width */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    /* Force the layout from row to columns */
    header.wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    /* Reduce the image size on mobile, the most possible */
    header.wrapper h1 img {
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

If you use Bootstrap, have a look at the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) about the grid system. They already have all you need to handle that.

Hope those give you a bit of help to move forward.

Have fun!

For the pagination, I would go for a

Comment: Hi @Geoffrey C. Thank you for your comment. I woul like to make the create new article button and the pagination not to overflow on mobile screens. I added:
`
@media (max-width: 768px){
    header{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
`
It seems to work fine. But I would like to make the pagination not to overflow(like the 'last>>' button in the attached screenshot). I'm a newbie in css and bootstrap, so my knowledge is really small.
I attached the default.html and the pagination.html. I think they are enought, but I'll share all my htmls.